# Cannot save views or create new ones - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I recently installed a Fusion theme called Creative on a Drupal6 installation and I cannot save any of the views that come with the theme after I've made changes to them. I'm also not able to create any new views. As soon as I save new views I get a "Page not found" error. I guess the problem comes in with the saving of views. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Update: I realised that this only occurs on my local machine and not on the live site.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit drastic, but [here's on instance of someone having a similar problem recently and reinstalling Views fixed the problem for them](https://drupal.org/node/1476944#comment-5716468).